# Adjusting current code to be able to add items from new table to the basket

Tags: python, django

My website is currently adapted to deal with things like adding to the cart, removing from the cart and creating an order, only on one Item table. I wanted to add different products to the site, so I need to create a new table, that will handle other items. The thing is, that I am not really sure how to properly implement that to my website, so things like adding to the cart and creating order would work with that new table as well.

So thats the model of the first Item table:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  price = models.FloatField()
  discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
  label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  description = models.TextField()
  image = models.ImageField()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
          'slug': self.slug
      })

  def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
      return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
          'slug': self.slug
      })

  def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
      return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
          'slug': self.slug
      })
```

When you add item to the cart it goes to this table:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Can I just add a new foreign key to this table and everything would work as it should? How to deal with things like adding product from just one table? The field for the other would be blank then?

order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
  start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
  ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(
      'Address', related_name='shipping_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

and finally the new table, that will store other items:

```
class Accessory(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  price = models.FloatField()
  discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
  label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  description = models.TextField()
  image = models.ImageField()
```

Anyone can help me get this to work with that new table called Accessory?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `Item` and `Accessory` model definitions, those two look very similar. My recommendation would be to create a `OneToOne` relationship between `Accessory` and `Item` tables, so you would not need to deal with this redundancy.

If you do it like this, all the functionalities related to `Item` table would be inherited by the `Accessory` table as well. I think it will reduce costs and overheads of changing your logic.

```
class Accessory(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    # other fields that will differ between Accessory and Item
```

You can even use the connected `Item` record as your `Accessory` model's `primary_key`.

Comment: After making the migrations and entering admin panel, I am getting an error `no such column: core_accessory.item_id` when I try to add new Accessory

Comment: After making migrations, you should apply them by running `python manage.py migrate` command.

Comment: I did that and i got a console message : `No migrations to apply.`

Comment: Ok I got a fresh database and it works now, but here's a problem - Can I have a different table for category for accessory as I have in my items?

Comment: You can add a `category` field to `Accessory` model. But you should be careful to use the `Accessory`'s own category and avoid using `ac.item.category` instead.

Comment: becasue right now when I am adding a new accesory I have to choose one of the category that is connected to the item table, is there a way to delete that field for accessory or replace it with a new table accessory_category?

Comment: When I am trying to display all results from table item using `item_list = Item.objects.all()` , I can see the products from Accessory table, is there a way to narrow it down just to table Item?